# How do you handle the "Too many files" problem when working in Bash?

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I many times have to work with directories containing hundreds of thousands of files, doing text matching, replacing and so on. If I go the standard route of, say

```
grep foo *
```

I get the too many files error message, so I end up doing

```
for i in *; do grep foo $i; done
```

or

```
find ../path/ | xargs -I{} grep foo "{}"
```

But these are less than optimal (create a new grep process per each file).

This looks like more of a limitation in the size of the arguments programs can receive, because the * in the for loop works alright. But, in any case, what's the proper way to handle this?

PS: Don't tell me to do grep -r instead, I know about that, I'm thinking about tools that do not have a recursive option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In newer versions of findutils, find can do the work of xargs (including the glomming behavior, such that only as many grep processes as needed are used):

```
find ../path -exec grep foo '{}' +
```

The use of `+` rather than `;` as the last argument triggers this behavior.

Comment: Great tip! I never knew of the "+" option.

Answer (score 6):

If there is a risk of filenames containing spaces, you should remember to use the -print0 flag to find together with the -0 flag to xargs:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H foo
```

Comment: I usually use `xargs -d '\n'` using newlines as the separators, since find outputs paths separated by newlines by default.

Comment: @ephemient, that's unsafe, as POSIX filesystems allow newlines within filenames.

Comment: Unsafe in what way? Yes, there is a possibility that grep will fail on certain filenames, but unless there is a security hole in grep itself, how is it unsafe?

Comment: @JesperE, it's not just a matter of failing, it's a matter of allowing arbitrary filenames to be injected. Think of someone creating `$'/tmp/\n/etc/passwd'`, and waiting for a process with root privileges to run cleanup. Obviously, consequences are more dire with `rm` than `grep`.

Comment: @JesperE, ...some `find` implementations will try to circumvent this by replacing newline characters with a literal `?` when not using something akin to `-print0` -- but relying on implementation-defined behavior for security isn't exactly a good practice, and these can be expanded when other poor practices (such as string-splitting for "list" expansion, thus triggering globbing behavior) are in place.

Answer (score 4):

xargs does not start a new process for each file. It bunches together the arguments. Have a look at the -n option to xargs - it controls the number of arguments passed to each execution of the sub-command.

Comment: As Ry4an mentioned, using xargs -I turns batching off.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see that

```
for i in *; do
    grep foo $i
done
```

would work since I thought the "too many files" was a shell limitation, hence it would fail for the for loop as well.

Having said that, I always let xargs do the grunt-work of splitting the argument list into manageable bits thus:

```
find ../path/ | xargs grep foo
```

It won't start a process per file but per group of files.

Comment: No, the "too many files" limitation is because the length of the arguments to the program being executed are restricted in size.  "for i in *" never leaves the current shell to execute another program, so it can't hit this limitation.

Comment: To echo and expand on the above comment -- it's a limit on combined environment variable and argv space common to any process invocation, not a shell limit. Glob expansions' memory allocations come off the heap -- they're not subject to that -- until and unless you try to put their results on a command line of an external command or into an environment variable (shell variables not exported to the environment are still heap-only, thus fine).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problems, but it seems that everything I came up with is already mentioned. Mostly, had two problems. Doing globs is expensive, doing ls on a million files directory takes forever (20+ minutes on one of my servers) and doing ls * on a million files directory takes forever and fails with "argument list too long" error.

```
find /some -type f -exec some command {} \;
```

seems to help with both problems. Also, if you need to do more complex operations on these files, you might consider to script your stuff into multiple threads. Here is a python primer for scripting CLI stuff.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-pythocli/?ca=dgr-lnxw06pythonunixtool&S_TACT=105AGX59&S_CMP=GR

Comment: Using find -exec grep foo ';' has the same problem as the original solution in that it execs an individual instance of grep for each file.