# Exclude a string from wildcard search in a shell

Tags: bash, wildcard

I am trying to exclude a certain string from a file search.

Suppose I have a list of files: file_Michael.txt, file_Thomas.txt, file_Anne.txt.

I want to be able and write something like

```
ls *<and not Thomas>.txt
```

to give me file_Michael.txt and file_Anne.txt, but not file_Thomas.txt.

The reverse is easy:

```
ls *Thomas.txt
```

Doing it with a single character is also easy:

```
ls *[^s].txt
```

But how to do it with a string?

Sebastian

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use inverse or negative wildcards when pattern matching in a unix/linux shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu)

Answer (score 19):

You can use find to do this:

```
$ find . -name '*.txt' -a ! -name '*Thomas.txt'
```

Comment: You might need to add `-maxdepth 1` to get similar behaviour to a simple wildcard

Answer (score 17):

With Bash

```
shopt -s extglob
ls !(*Thomas).txt
```

where the first line means "set extended globbing", see the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) for more information.

Some other ways could be:

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*.txt" -a -not -iname "*thomas*" \)

ls *txt |grep -vi "thomas"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looping a wildcard, just skip the rest of the iteration if there is something you want to exclude.

```
for file in *.txt; do
    case $file in *Thomas*) continue;; esac
    : ... do stuff with "$file"
done
```