# Exclude specific filename from shell globbing

Tags: shell

I want to excluse a specific filename (say, `fubar.log`) from a shell (bash) globbing string, `*.log`. Nothing of what I tried seems to work, because globbing doesn't use the standard RE set.

Test case : the directory contains

```
fubar.log
fubaz.log
barbaz.log
text.txt
```

and only `fubaz.log barbaz.log` must be expanded by the glob.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use inverse or negative wildcards when pattern matching in a unix/linux shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu) This is a very close subset of the other one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

if you are using bash

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
ls !(fubar).log
```

or without `extglob`

```
shopt -u extglob
for file in !(fubar).log
do
  echo "$file"
done
```

or

```
for file in *log
do
   case "$file" in
     fubar* ) continue;;
     * ) echo "do your stuff with $file";;
   esac 
done
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a solution without extglob?

Comment: A rejected edit suggested that this is needed in the case without extglob: `shopt -u extglob` I don't have the knowledge to Judge it though.

Comment: `shopt -u extglob` turns off extglobs. Having extglobs turned off doesn't make extglob syntax work, though, so that (now-accepted?) edit looks like a bad one to me -- the `shopt -s extglob` branch of this answer is fine, and so is the `case` statement version, but I'm deeply suspicious of the other.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use grep? For example:

*ls |grep -v fubar|while read line; do echo "reading $line"; done;*

And here is the output:

*reading barbaz.log
reading fubaz.log
reading text.txt*

Comment: Because the glob string is given to a program (logrotate). So I need a glob string.

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Even if you don't have extglobs to do `!(*fubar*)`, less buggy to do it like: `for file in *; [[ $file = *fubar* ]] && continue; echo "Reading $line"; done`