# Loop over all *.js files in a directory skipping *.spec.js files in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-findutils

```
FILES=`find . -type f -name '*.js'`
for file in $FILES
do
  # some task
done
```

This will loop over all *.js files but let's say there are some *.spec.js* files as well which I want to skip.

```
a.js
a.spec.js
b.js
x.spec.js
c.js
```

should iterate over:

```
a.js
b.js
c.js
```

Comment: See: [Exclude specific filename from shell globbing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2643929/3776858) and [What expands to all files in current directory recursively?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1690809/3776858)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the code you looking for :

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*.js" -not -iname "*.spec.js" \)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a condition that implements that you do *not* want a specific file name pattern:

```
FILES=`find . -type f -name '*.js'`
for file in $FILES
do
  if [[ $file != *.spec.js ]]; then
    echo $file
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the negate `!` feature of find to not match files with specific names. Additionally using `wholename` should be faster I think.

`find . ! -name '*.spec*'`

So your final command (not tested) would be:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.js' -wholename '*.php'
```