# Ripgrep to only exclude a file in the root of the folder

Tags: shell, grep, ripgrep

If I have my folder like this:

```
dir:
    ├── 1.index1.html
    ├── 2.index2.html
    ├── 3.index3.html
    ├── a
    │   ├── 1.index1.html
    │
```

How can I tell `ripgrep` in the command to exclude only the file `index1.html` in the root folder, but still searching the `index1.html` in folder `a`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude specific filename from shell globbing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643929/exclude-specific-filename-from-shell-globbing)

Comment: See linked post, try `!(index1.html)` this will allow all files, including any files with this filename nested in subdirectories, excluding this filename only in the current directory.

Comment: The linked question is not a duplicate and this question should not be closed. The linked question shows how to solve the OP's problem in a particular shell environment with a special option. But ripgrep can solve this problem independent of your shell.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

ripgrep has support for this, regardless of the globbing syntax that is support by your shell because its support is independent of the shell.

ripgrep's `-g/--glob` flag allows you to include or exclude files. And in particular, it follows the same semantics that gitignore uses (see `man gitignore`). This means that if you start a glob pattern with a `/`, then it will only match that specific path relative to where ripgrep is running. For example:

```
$ tree
.
├── a
│   └── index1.html
├── index1.html
├── index2.html
└── index3.html

1 directory, 4 files

$ rg --files
index1.html
a/index1.html
index2.html
index3.html

$ rg --files -g '!index1.html'
index2.html
index3.html

$ rg --files -g '!/index1.html'
index2.html
index3.html
a/index1.html
```

When using the `-g` flag, the `!` means to ignore files matching that pattern. When we run `rg --files -g '!index1.html'`, it will result in ignoring *all* files named `index1.html`. But if we use `!/index1.html`, then it will only ignore the top-level `index1.html`. Similarly, if we use `!/a/index1.html`, then it would only ignore that file:

```
$ rg --files -g '!/a/index1.html'
index1.html
index2.html
index3.html
```

ripgrep has more details about the `-g/--glob` flag in its [guide](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/GUIDE.md#manual-filtering-globs).