# In Linux, how to copy all the files not starting with a given string?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, cp

I tried with the following command:

```
cp src_folder/[!String]* dest_folder
```

However, this command will copy all the files that don't start with any of the characters 'S','t','r','i','n','g' instead of copying files that don't start with "String".

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A variation on Konrad answer, using `cp` option `-t` to specify target directory simplifies the last command. It creates a single `cp` process to copy all the files.

```
ls src_folder | grep -v '^String' | xargs cp -t dest_folder
```

- list all files in `src_folder`
- filter out all those that start with `String`
- copy all remaining files to `dest_dir`

Answer (score 5):

In bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
cp src_folder/!(String*) dest_folder
```

Comment: @Joel: Enables extended globbing in bash.

Answer (score 3):

```
ls src_folder | grep -v '^String' | xargs -J % -n1 cp % dest_folder
```

This will

- list all files in `src_folder`
- filter out all those that start with `String` (so that the rest remains)
- Invoke the `cp` command

  - once for each of those files (`-n1` says to call `cp` for each of them separately)
  - using, as its arguments, `% dest_folder`, where `%` is replaced by the actual file name.

Comment: My `xargs` (Debian Testing) doesn't have a `-J` option. Did you mean `-I`?

Comment: @maxelost: I’m using the BSD version from OS X. Option `-I` does something else. It sucks that all distributions have different switches on their POSIX tools. :-( So much for standardization.

Answer (score 1):

```
cp src_folder/!(String*) dest_folder
```

Try that
~ Chris

Comment: I get an error message:

    syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: For some reason that one works for me. Try the command that Ignacio posted (Adjusted in my answer above - you don't need the shopt -s extglob)