# How to copy over all files from one directory to another excluding ones that start with a given string in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory containing a large amount of files ~1gb. I need to copy over all of them except ones that start with "name" to a different directory. I tried using this: "ls src_folder | grep -v '^name' | xargs cp -t dest_folder" from this pervious question [In Linux, how to copy all the files not starting with a given string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669851/in-linux-how-to-copy-all-the-files-not-starting-with-a-given-string)

I get the following error when trying to copy over test1.txt from src_folder which contains test1.txt and name.txt to dest_folder

cp: cannot stat `test1.txt': No such file or directory

My current work around is to copy over all of the files, then use find to delete the ones starting with "name" in the dest_folder. This works, but I imagine I could save some time by only copying over the files I really want. Any suggestions?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4670152/9952196) from your linked question is the best approach.

Comment: @Shawn This worked, don't know how I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, if you have a **large** number of files in the directory, `/bin/ls` might return to many arguments.  In such a case, use `find`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the shell option `extglob`. This option extends the bash's pattern  matching, so you can use more advanced expressions.

```
shopt -s extglob
cp src_folder/!(name*) dest_folder
```

For more info run `nam bash` and look for `extglob`.