# bash: Inverse (ie. NOT) shell wildcard expansion?

Tags: bash, glob

Is there a way of handling invers bash v4 shell expansion, ie. treat all files NOT like a wildcard? I need to `rm` all files that are not of the format `'Folder-???'` in this case and was wondering if there is a shorter (ie. built-in) way then doing a

```
for file in *
do
  [[ $i =~ \Folder-...\ ]] && rm '$i'
done
```

loop. (the example doesn't work, btw...)

Just out of bash learning curiosity...

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that and have to use regular expressions instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use inverse or negative wildcards when pattern matching in a unix/linux shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu)

Comment: @Tomas untrue; extglobs are reversible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -- !(Folder-???)
```

Answer (score 4):

@Dimitre has the [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516888/bash-inverse-ie-not-shell-wildcard-expansion/7517079#7517079) for bash. A portable solution is to use `case`:

```
for file in *; do
  case "$file" in
    Folder-???) : ;;
    *) do stuff here ;;
  esac
done
```

Another bash solution is to use the pattern matching operator inside `[[ ... ]]` ([documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-g_t_005b_005b-57))

```
for file in *; do
  if [[ "$file" != Folder-??? ]]; then
    do stuff here
  fi
done
```

Comment: Hi @glenn, just to add that in both cases: `case varname ...` and _varname_ inside `[[ ... ]]` no shell word/field splitting is performed, so the identifier doesn't need to be quoted (and the quoting in this context, of course, is not harmful either).

Answer (score 3):

In case you are ok with `find`, you can invert `find`'s predicates with `-not`.

As in

```
find -not -name 'Folder-???' -delete
```

(note this matches recursively among other differences to shell glob matching, but I assume you know `find` well enough)