# Linux, rename files with bash 'no such file or directory' error

Tags: linux, bash, find, pathname

I'm trying to add a prefix to all files that are not `.sh` files in the current directory, and all subdirectories, with `bash` using `find`.

The problem is that I get an error:

```
mv: cannot move './test.txt' to 'PRE_./test.txt': No such file or directory
```

My one-liner is:

```
find -type f ! -name "*.sh" -exec sh -c 'mv "{}" PRE_"{}"' _ {} \;
```

I tried `xargs` with `rename`, too:

```
find -type f ! -name "*.sh" -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/(.*)$/PRE_$1/'
```

But I got the same error.
What's wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `cannot move './test.txt' to 'PRE_./test.txt'` seems like a pretty clear message - look at the new name you are trying to give it, is that what you wanted? You are prefixing the entire path, not just the filename.

Comment: Just in the current directory, or also in all subdirectories of the current directory?

Comment: Have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199301/find-files-based-on-name-and-moving-them-with-renaming-simultaneously

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention: i want to rename files in all subdirectories too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find -type f ! -name "*.sh" -exec rename -n 's|.*/\K|PRE_|' {} +
```

- `.*/` matches upto last `/` in file name
- by using `\K` lookbehind, we can avoid need of capture group in this case

Remove `-n` option from `rename` once it shows correct renaming

Comment: Thanks that is what i need

Answer (score 1):

`find` returns the path from `.` all the way to the file, so each `find` result in starts with `./` when you begin your search in the current directory.  As a result, your new filename is `PRE_./test.txt`, which is `test.txt` in a directory called `PRE_.`.  Since there is no directory called `PRE_.`, `mv` can't move `test.txt` into that directory, so gives you the error message you saw.

If you are only renaming files in the current directory, and not subdirectories, you can just use bash:

```
shopt -s extglob 
for f in !(*.sh) ; do [[ -d "$f" ]] || mv "$f" "PRE_$f" ; done
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7517079/2877364) for the `!(pattern)` construct in bash, available when `extglob` is enabled.  It returns all filenames *not* matching `pattern`.

For files in all subdirectories, too, use:

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
for f in **/!(*.sh) ; do [[ -d "$f" ]] || mv "$f" "${f%/*}/PRE_${f##*/}" ; done
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120375/63804) for globstar.  The `%` and `##` chop the path components and stick the `PRE_` into the right place, at the beginning of the filename.

**Edit** The `[[ -d "$f" ]] ||` in both of the above prevents the loop from renaming directories.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to change files in subdirectories you can use this:

```
find -type f ! -name "*.sh" -printf "%f\n" | xargs -r rename 's/(.*)$/PRE_$1/'
```

the problem was ./ infront of the file names.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to not use `{}` directly in the argument to `sh -c`, but to pass its value in as an argument. Then you can use parameter expansion operations as usual to modify its value. Here, we'll split the argument into its directory and file name components, then reassemble them including the filename prefix `PRE_` to use as an argument to `mv`.

```
script='
d=${1%/*}
f=${1#$d}
mv "$1" "$d/PRE_$f"
'
find -type f ! -name "*.sh" -exec sh -c "$script" _ {} \;
```

(This is just a slight change from your original attempt; you were passing `{}` as an argument, but not using it. Instead, you were "embedding" the value directly into the string passed to `sh`.)

You can also use the `-exec +` form to minimize the number of calls to `sh`, by passing multiple file names and iterating over them in the shell. (This starts to converge with the pure `bash` solution suggested by @cxw, but maintaining POSIX, as well as `bash` 3.x, compatibility):

```
script='
for arg;
 d=${arg%/*}
 f=${arg#$d}
 mv "$1" "$d/PRE_$f"
done
'
find -type f ! -name "*.sh" -exec sh -c "$script" _ {} +
```

Comment: Won't this try to move `./foo/bar/bat` to `./PRE_foo/bar/bat` rather than `./foo/bar/PRE_bat`?  It looks to me like `$f` will get `foo/bar/bat`.  (I may, of course, be missing something.)

Comment: Yeah. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

On many Linux distributions, the rename command is not available by default.

If your system is missing the rename command, install it with:

For Ubuntu and Debian, use

```bash
sudo apt install rename
```

For CentOS and Fedora, use

```bash
sudo yum install prename
```