# python glob for "excluding pattern"

Tags: python, regex, wildcard, glob

Basically I want to screen for the following files in python using glob.glob module:

```
log_fasdsaf
log_bifsd72q
log_asfd8
...
```

but excluding:

```
log_fdsaf_7832
log_fsafn_fsda
log_dsaf8_8d
...
```

Naively played around with linux wildcard (eg log_*[!_]* but apparently not working). [How can I use inverse or negative wildcards when pattern matching in a unix/linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu) seems not helping, and thanks for advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  The pattern you are looking for is `log_[^_]*`.  It says it must have 'log_' followed by zero or more non-underscore characters.

Comment: Actually this didn't work. The files I am looking for is "log_" following by some characters, in which there are no more underscores. The wildcard "log_[^_]*" only refers to the file names starting from "log_" and not directly followed by another "_".

Comment: @HailiangZhang I missed you are using `glob`.  The above is regex.  I think the answer is you aren't going to be able to do it with `glob`.  `Glob` is very limited, specifically it does not allow you to specify a repeating pattern.  I would get the results from `os.listdir` and use the regex above for filtering.

Comment: For glob try Unix pattern: log_[!_]*

Answer (score 2):

you are using the wrong character to say `none of this character`...

If you're looking to find any file which has `log_` at the beginning, and then a load of characters where none of them are `_`, then you just need to do this:

`log_[^_]*`