# copy all *.so files excluding libgcc*.so

Tags: linux, copy

lib1.a
lib2.a
lib1.so
lib2.so
libgcc1.so
libgcc2.so
libgcc3.so
lib3.so

How can I copy all `*.so` files excluding `libgcc*.so` i.e. copy the following files:

lib1.so
lib2.so
lib3.so

?

Comment: Copy to temp folder, delete the ones you don't need, copy the rest to the final destination?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu might have some pointers.

Comment: How strict is the requirement to not copy `libgcc`? Could you copy everything and then delete just those? Either way, you probably want to start with `find` or `ls | grep`, both piped to `xargs cp`. To exclude things, use `grep -v`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`find`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/find.1.php):

```
find path/to/src-dir -name '*.so' ! -name 'libgcc*.so' \
    -exec cp '{}' /path/to/dst-dir \;
```

Answer (score 7):

In `bash`, you can use extended globbing:

```
shopt -s extglob
cp !(libgcc*).so destination/
```