# Glob pattern to match non-hidden filenames that don't start with a particular string

Tags: bash, glob

I'm pretty inexperienced to globbing in general. How would one go about writing a glob pattern that matches filenames *not* starting with, say, "ab" but still *need a length of at least 2*? i.e. "start with something 2-letter string other than "ab"" This is a homework question, and only basic bash globs are allowed, and must work with "echo <glob here>".

Note: the question verbatim is

> (Non-hidden) files in the current directory whose names contain at least two characters, but do not start with ab.

printed on paper. I'm pretty sure I didn't misunderstand anything. The requirements are

> For each of the following file search criteria, provide a globbing pattern that matches
>   the criterion. Your answer in each case should be a text file with the following format:

```
echo <pattern>
```

My current attempt is `echo {a[!b]*,[!a.]?*}` but somehow it gets no points with the automatic grader which actually runs your file against a test case automatically without human intervention.

Comment: Due to the odd formulation of the question, I suspect your teacher is looking for the answer `[^a][^b]*`. It's a common mistake, and several correct (but necessarily non-basic) solutions are given in the answers.

Comment: @thatotherguy, I think `[^a]?*` is a better answer, less wrong anyway

Comment: @perreal: he knows that, but he also assumes (like I do) the answer to this question actually doesn't exist, and offers up some misconception the _teacher_ may have about what the answer should be, which is actually wrong.

Comment: Grading is all automatic by running your glob against a test cases. A program marks your programs (this is University of Waterloo, where the robot takeover is starting xD). My current glob is {a[!b]*,[!a.]?*} which I think is pretty smart but gets 0/1. I'll update my post.

Comment: @EricDong: it would still give back a `a[!b]*` when there are not files starting with a + a non b character.

Answer (score 4):

For a single letter, this would do:

```
$ echo [!a]?*
```

However, for 2 letters (and assuming files can also start with numbers or punctuation or all kinds of other things), I can only think of this without resorting to `shopt`:

```
$ GLOBIGNORE=ab* 
$ echo *
```

Well, now, technically, this would work:

```
$ echo [!a]?* [a][!b]*
```

BUT this would leave a nasty `[a][!b]*` in our results if there are *no* files starting with an `a`+1 or more extra characters, which would not only be undesirable, but even considered a bug in any application, so on that grounds I would not consider it a valid answer. To omit that `[a][!b]*`, we *have* to resort to  `nullglob` (and if `extglob` isn't allowed, `nullglob` probably isn't either):

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ echo [!a]?* [a][!b]*
```

Fwiw, `extglob` would be:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
```

<del>$ echo !(ab*)</del>
That previous answer would match files with less then 2 characters, so like @perreal says:

```
$ @([^a]?|?[^b])*
```

Comment: extglob not allowed. Must use vanilla globs that go immediately after echo with no pipes etc.

Comment: @EricDong: well, with vanilla globs the `GLOBIGNORE` is all I can give you. I seriously doubt it's possible without that or a `shopt`, unless you use the `echo [!a]?* [a][!b]*` and you don't mind `[a][!b]*` is in the results if there are no files starting with `a`.

Comment: Well, yes, I could elaborate why I only use it with a `nullglob` for completeness sake indeed. Editing...

Comment: In the academy you can assume anything, anyway

Comment: Well, the OP mentions that as a file, but mentions `test cases`, suggesting multiple file lists to test against...

Answer (score 2):

Starting with "a" or "b" OR with "ab"? For the later:

```
ab*
```

Needless to say, you have to specify a path that resolves (relative or absolute):

```
/path/to/ab*
```

---

To your updated question:

```
{b,c,d,e,f...}{a,c,d,e,f...}*
```

Should work, note that `...` is not actually valid, but I won't write the whole alphabet here. :P

Comment: Sorry, I asked the wrong question. I massively edited my post now.

Comment: @EricDong: Updated again to allow filenames that start with `ba`.

Comment: @EricDong: True. Then all I can think of is something like `{ac,..,az,ba,bb,bc,..,zz}*` but I highly doubt they would ask you for such a convulsed solution if no cleaner alternative exists. I don't know, sorry.

Comment: @EricDong: Do you have access to extglob http://stackoverflow.com/a/217017/89771?

Comment: No. We can only do echo fill in the blank. In fact we submit a file containing the fill in the blank part which is then automatically graded by running it against test cases.

Comment: @EricDong: Dammit. I'm sleepy. Ignore it and have a nice night. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s extglob         # turn on extended globbing
echo @([^a]?|?[^b])*
```

Comment: extglob not allowed. We need to make it work with something that you put immediately after echo. ; not allowed and not a big shell script.

Comment: Ah, you're right my `extglob` did not meet the requirement of 'minimal 2 letters'.

Answer (score 0):

My original `echo {a[!b]*,[!a.]?*}` is correct works very well. The teacher actually set up the test cases wrong, so everybody got marked incorrectly and got a remark just now.

Comment: Since {a[!b]*,[!a.]?*} expands immediately (brace expansion happens before other expansions) to a[!b]* [!a.]?* which is actually shorter, I can see no reason to use brace expansion in this way. If you wanted to express the fact that both subpatterns have a common suffix, {a[!b],[!a.]?}* expands to the same thing as your original and is also shorter, though still longer than its expansion.