# Can OR expressions be used in ${var//OLD/NEW} replacements?

Tags: regex, string, bash, glob

I was testing some string manipulation stuff in a `bash` script and I've quickly realized it doesn't understand regular expressions (at least not with the syntax I'm using for string operations), then I've tried some glob expressions and it seems to understand some of them, some not. To be specific:

```
FINAL_STRING=${FINAL_STRING//<title>/$(get_title)}
```

is the main operation I'm trying to use and the above line works, replacing all occurrences of `<title>` with `$(get_title)` on `$FINAL_STRING`... and

```
local field=${1/#*:::/}
```

works, assigning `$1` with everything from the beginning to the first occurrence of `:::` replaced by nothing (removed). However `#` do what I'd expect `^` to do. *Plus* when I've tried to use the `{,,}` glob expression here:

```
FINAL_STRING=${FINAL_STRING//{<suffix>,<extension>}/${SUFFIX}}
```

to replace any occurrence of `<suffix>` OR `<extension>` by `${SUFFIX}` , it works not.

So I see it doesn't take regex and it also doesn't take glob patterns... so what Does it take? Are there any exhaustive listing of what symbols/expressions are understood by plain bash string operations (particularly substring replacement)? Or are `*`, `?`, `#`, `##`, `%` and `%%` the only valid stuff?

*(I'm trying to rely only on **plain bash**, without calling `sed` or `grep` to do what I want)*

Comment: A good StackOverflow question is limited in scope -- asking for a completely exhaustive list of a sublanguage is broad enough to be eligible to be closed for that reason. That said, if you *want* an extended discussion of native string operations in bash, BashFAQ #100 provides such: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100

Comment: The bash-hackers page on parameter expansion is also an excellent reference: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: As for using a brace expansion inside a PE, I don't know why you'd expect that to work in the first place. Brace expansions **create multiple words**; a parameter expansion that parses as multiple words isn't permissible at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah... I was just testing possibilities. Now I'm using `extglob` option on (`shopt -s extglob`) and replaced `{a,b,c}` by `@(a|b|c)`... Very useful, since, according to that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191622/why-would-i-not-leave-extglob-enabled-in-bash, there's no reason to leave `extglob` off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gory details can be found in the bash manual, *[Shell Expansions](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC29)* section. The complete picture is surprisingly complex.

What you're doing is described in the *[Shell Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC32)* section. You'll see that the pattern in

```
${parameter/pattern/string}
```

uses the *[Filename Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC37)* rules, and those don't include *[Brace Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC30)* - that is done earlier when processing the command line arguments. Filename expansion "only" does `?`, `*` and `[...]` matching (unless `extglob` is set).

But parameter expansion does a bit more than just filename expansion, notably the anchoring you noticed with `#` or `%`.

Comment: Now, with `extglob` turned on, this line `INPUT_INFO=${INPUT_INFO// +( ):+( )/:::}` freezes the execution... Any ideas on why?

Comment: Can't see anything obviously wrong with that. Please post a new question with enough info to reproduce your problem (including your actual input and what you're trying to achieve).

Answer (score 1):

**bash** *does* in fact handle regex; specifically, the `[[ =~ ]]` operator, which you can then assign to a variable using the magic variable `$BASH_REMATCH`. It's funky, but it works.

See: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions

Note this is a bash-only <strike>hack</strike> feature.

For code that works in shells besides bash as well, the old school way of doing something like this is indeed to use `#`/`##`/`%`/`%%` along with a loop around a `case` statement (which supports basic `*` glob matching).