# Pattern match does not work in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, glob, extglob

Using the pattern match `!("file1")` does not work within a bash script but will work on the command line.

For example:

```
ls  !("file1"|"file2")
```

This will list all files in directory except `file1` and `file2`.

When that line is executed in a script this error is displayed:

```
./script.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./script.sh: line 1: ` ls  !("file1"|"file2") '
```

Regardless what is used `rm -v !("file1")`. The same error takes place. What is going on here why does this not work in a script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use inverse or negative wildcards when pattern matching in a unix/linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/216995/608639), [List all files that do not match pattern using ls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12634013/608639), etc. And related is [Why would I not leave extglob enabled in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17191622/608639)

Comment: run it using `source script.sh`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The extended glob syntax you are trying to use is turned off by default; you have to enable it separately in each script where you want to use it.

```
shopt -s extglob
```

[Scripts should not use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) though I imagine you were using it merely as a placeholder here.

Answer (score 5):

Globbing doesn't work that way unless you enable `extglob` shell opt. Instead, I recommend using `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name '<NAME>' -or -name '<NAME>' -delete
```

*before running this command with `-delete` ensure the output is correct*

Answer (score 3):

Method with default settings and no external procs:

```
for f in *; do [[ $f =~ ^file[12]$ ]] || echo "$f"; done
```