# Pattern works in interactive shell but not in script

Tags: bash, glob, extglob

In my interactive shell I can store a pattern in a variable

```
$ targets="?(pcm52|pcm61)"
$ ls -l config/devdesc.$targets
-rw-r--r-- 1 kfa kfa 113 Dec 16 13:43 config/devdesc.pcm52
-rw-r--r-- 1 kfa kfa  14 Dec 16 13:44 config/devdesc.pcm61
```

But if I create a shell script

```
targets="?(pcm52|pcm61)"
ls -l config/devdesc.$targets
```

I get this error running it

```
$ bash -x /tmp/e.sh
+ targets='?(pcm52|pcm61)'
+ ls -l 'config/devdesc.?(pcm52|pcm61)'
ls: cannot access 'config/devdesc.?(pcm52|pcm61)': No such file or directory
```

Why does it fail when put into a script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pattern match does not work in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55546727/pattern-match-does-not-work-in-bash-script)

Comment: @l%c3%a9a-gris Yes that is the exact same problem. Just ran into the how to formulate the right search question.

Answer (score 7):

From Bash manual page:

> **If the `extglob` shell option is enabled** using the `shopt` builtin, several extended pattern matching operators are recognized.

So just add `shopt -s extglob` to the beginning your `e.sh` script, since it does not inherit that non-default option from your interactive session.

Comment: So specifically to "Why does it fail when put into a script?": because you are using an extended glob pattern, support for those depends on a non-default shell option, and that option is not inherited by your script.

Comment: Or you could also have noted that this question is a duplicate, because it  recurrent and has been addressed here at multiple occasions.