# How to find all directories except the ones under .git directory?

Tags: linux, find

In my git repository I have a small directory structure under the root directory along with a very big directory structure under `.git` directory. I would like to use the `find` command to get a list of all directories under `$(REPO_DIR)` but not including any directory under `$(REPO_DIR)/.git` (including). I tried something like

```
find $(REPO_DIR) -type d ! -name ".git"
```

and

```
find $(REPO_DIR) -wholename ".git" -prune -type d
```

But unfortunately none worked as expected, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 find . -type d -not -iwholename '*.git*'
```

or:

```
find . -type d  -not -path './.git*'
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you're using bash, you could turn on `extglob` mode.

```
shopt -s extglob
```

This would allow you to do (from within `$(REPO_DIR)`):

```
find !(.git) -type d
```

See this answer for full details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/217017/24

Comment: Sorry, didn't work, it runs from `shell` command in a makefile
`VPATH := . $(shell find $(REPO_DIR) -type d -not -wholename "*.git*")`

Comment: Ah, then it definitely won't work for you. Guess the `$(REPO_PATH)` variable format should have clued me in...