# How do I find all files that do not begin with a given prefix in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep, find

I have a bunch of files in a folder:

```
foo_1 
foo_2
foo_3
bar_1
bar_2
buzz_1
...
```

I want to find all the files that **do not** start with a given prefix and save the list to a text file.  Here is an example for the files that **do** have a given prefix:

```
find bar_* > Positives.txt
```

Comment: are you familiar with `grep -v`?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu

Comment: @BroSlow Yes that question is similar but I would argue that this is more discoverable.  I did not think to search for the terms in that question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick in any shell

```
ls | grep -v '^prefix'
```

The -v option inverts grep's search logic, making it filter out all matches.
Using grep instead of find you can use powerful regular expressions instead of the limited glob patterns.

Comment: Gnu find implements the `-regex` test for "powerful" regular expressions.

Comment: As stated, it inverts the output logic: instead of outputting matching lines, it outputs non-matching lines.

Comment: ah yes - sorry missed that.

Comment: @rici Right, but it is best practice in shell programming to avoid GNUisms. In my career they invariably cause portability problems. If I can, I strive to write POSIX compliant scripts.

Answer (score 12):

If you're doing subdirectories as well:

```
find . ! -name "bar_*"
```

Or, equivalently,

```
find . -not -name "*bar_*"
```

Comment: don't forget to escape the `!` on the shell prompt

Comment: Curious to see a situation where we really need to escape `!`, have never experienced it.

Comment: @grebneke The `!` needs to be escaped when it's mixed with some characters together as one word.

Comment: Btw. Instead of `!`, `-not` can be used.

Comment: @kenorb Fine, so basically we agree that a single `!` never needs to be escaped in everyday scripting.

Answer (score 5):

You want to find filenames *not* starting with `bar_*`?

recursive:

```
find ! -name 'bar_*' > Negatives.txt
```

top directory:

```
find -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'bar_*' > Negatives.txt
```

Comment: But that's recursive.

Comment: don't forget to escape the `!` on the shell prompt

Comment: @zmo - Yes I know *man find* says `!` might need to be escaped, but I have never encountered an occasion when that is true. Do you have an example of shell or situation when `\!` really is necessary?

Comment: It's passed as an argument regardless of escaping.

Comment: @BroSlow - I don't understand what that implies? You're saying we should escape ! or not?

Comment: it actually depends on how your shell is configured… and if you put quotes around the `"!"` you may have surprises. Usually `!` is for history related stuff… though I'm not sure a lone `!` will actually do something.

Comment: @zmo - Do you have an example of a shell configuration where escaping the naked `!` is required?

Comment: well, not with my shells zsh/bash :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using bash and wildcards:  `ls [!bar_]*`.  There is a caveat:  the order of the letters is not important, so `rab_something.txt` will not be listed.

Comment: Since you're using Bash, you might as well use extended globs here: `printf '%s\n' !(bar_*) > Positives.txt`. Don't forget to turn extended globs on with `shopt -s extglob` if you use this in scripts.

Answer (score 0):

With extended globs:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls !(bar_*) > filelist.txt
```

The `!(pattern)` matches anything *but* `pattern`, so `!(bar_*)` is any filename that does *not* start with `bar_`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an extra requirement, the files must end with the `.py` extension. So I use:

```
find . -name "*.py" | grep -v prefix_
```

In your case, to just exclude files with `prefix_`:

```
find . | grep -v prefix_
```

Note that this includes all sub-directories. There are many ways to do this, but it can be easy to remember for those already familiar with `find` and `grep -v` which excludes results.