# Recursively find all php files not starting with a comment

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

Is there any useful combination of commands (sed/grep/find etc.) I can use for detecting .php files not starting with a comment? I could write a little script of course, but I'd rather use shell commands.

Matching pattern:

```
<?php
/*
```

I'd like searching in the contents of the file, not the file names.

I have to deal with a hacked website where code-injection follows a certain pattern.

```
<?php $code....
/*
```

or

```
<?php
$code....
/*
```

Comment: [Get inspired for this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368838/how-do-i-find-all-files-that-do-not-begin-with-a-given-prefix-in-bash) and give us more code next time.

Comment: I am **not** searching for filenames. And there is no more code I can provide, since the pattern I'd like to grep all the files for is `<?php\n/*`

Comment: If you're not searching for the filenames, what is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gnu grep` you can use this recursive search:

```
grep -rvlz $'^[[:space:]]*<?php\n/\*' --include='*.php'
```

Comment: I liked the approach but it didn't work out, since it is grepping the whole file, and only returns files which do not contain _any_ comment. I have to search for the first few bytes only.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Can you explain the `^[[:space:]]*`-magic, please?

Comment: That is POSIX class property for matching any whitespace including new lines. Anchor ^ makes sure we match it at start only.

Comment: @EdMorton: Fair point. `-E` wasn't needed here and got added as mistake. I made an edit using my mobile this morning without testing. It is fixed now

Answer (score 1):

This will detect all php files that start with a php tag;

```
find ./ -iname '*.php' | xargs head -v -n 1 | grep -B 1 '<?php'
```

- Find all files with php extensions.
- head the first line and include the filename.
- grep this output to find any files that start with php tag.
- `-B 1`: keep 1 line before the match so we get the filename.

This is quick and dirty, you can get fancy to make the output nicer or make it more robust.

Answer (score 0):

From the shell you could use this little awk script to find out if the file starts **not** with the comment:

```
awk 'NR==2 && f$0!="<?php/*"{print FILENAME}NR>2{exit 1}{f=$0}' file.php
```

To apply the script recursively to a directory use:

```
find -name '*.php' \
  -exec awk 'NR==2 && f$0!="<?php/*"{print FILENAME}NR>2{exit 1}{f=$0}' {} \;
```

Possible spaces are a limitation to the above solution but it can be easily adapted to that by removing all possible spaces before comparing against `<php?/*`

Answer (score -1):

`awk` is your friend:

```
 find /your/path/here -type f -iname "*.php" -exec \
 awk 'FNR==2{if($0~/^\/\*/){print FILENAME};exit}' {} \;
```

**Notes**

1. `{}` is the argument passed to `awk` by `find`.
2. awk builtin `FILENAME` contains the current file being processed
3. `$0~/^\/\*/` searches for `/*` in the beginning of the second line
4. `FNR==2` looks chooses the record number to process, `exit` is used to exit awk after processing the needed record.

Answer (score -1):

The UNIX tool to find files is the very appropriately named `find` and the UNIX tool do to general purpose text manipulation is `awk`:

```
find . -name '*.php' -print |
xargs awk -v RS='^$' 'index($0,"<?php\n/*")==1{print FILENAME}'
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS. We use index() to enforce a string rather than regexp search since your target string contains multiple regexp metacharacters so this saves us escaping them all.

Comment: Thanks. Awk was always a mystery to me but your solution doesn't seem to work completely. I am not quite sure if this might be due to the different kind of line endings (\r\n vs \n). Also I was searching for files **not** matching the pattern. :)

Comment: Yes if your line endings are `\r\n` then just change `\n` to `\r\n` in the script but that can't be it since the solution you accepted assumes `\n` line endings. If you want to search for files that do *not* start with the string, just change `==` to `!=`.