# POSIX Regex: Exclude a specified word in the list using Regex

Tags: regex, linux, grep, regex-negation, linux-mint

I have a below **word list**:

```
www.home.example.com
www.example.com
home.example.com
google.com
example.com
child.example.com
sameer.example.com
sameer.google.com
```

I need a regex which only matches `child domains of example.com`, meaning I need the below answer:

```
www.home.example.com
home.example.com
child.example.com
sameer.example.com
```

But without using `egrep -v` option.

I have tried `egrep -i '(([(a-zA-Z0-9\-\.|^www)]*)\.example\.com)'` but did not work. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try `grep -v '^red$'`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, looks like this is working, make it as a answer, so that I can upvote your answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, but is there a way I can skip using -v? Because not sure whether my device will support -v or not. Can I use something like `!`

Comment: Then I need to know if this is the actual data. Are you really after excluding a `red` line? Or is it just a "placeholder" and the real data is more complex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find all files that do not begin with a given prefix in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368838/how-do-i-find-all-files-that-do-not-begin-with-a-given-prefix-in-bash)

Comment: @ceving: Well, it is a bit different since the whole line needs to be "excluded", but OP is updating the question now, so it might turn out the solution will be even more "different".

Comment: @ceving, now modified the question and this is no more a duplicate,

Comment: Why  is `sameer.google.com` expected to match? Isn't it a subdomain of `google.com`? Then, `sameer.example.com` should also be an expected match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, requesting you to delete your answer for now which has the keyword red, just to avoid down votes.

Comment: You might use a PCRE regex with `-P` option as Roman suggests. There is a way to use it without PCRE option, I believe, but it will be rather messy then.

Comment: My device uses POSIX, PCRE is not supported on my device and I am using a custom kernel.

Comment: I added an ERE regex solution, please check.

Comment: `grep -v` is specified by POSIX. Is there some actual reason to not use it (i.e. is there some actual system that doesn't have it)? Or is this more like a puzzle?

Comment: @manjesh23: You may l remove the question if *you* want to get rid of minus points. Your requirements are rather puzzling.

Comment: @manjesh23: Shall I remove my answer?

Comment: I am not able to remove my question

Comment: I removed my answer. Perhaps, you can only remove a question if there is only one unupvoted answer. I do not know as I never asked a question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

***grep*** approach (with PCRE):

```
grep -Pi '(?<!www)\.example\.com' file
```

---

without PCRE:

```
cat file | grep -Ei '\.example\.com' | grep -Ev '^w{3}\.example\.com'
```

The output:

```
www.home.example.com
home.example.com
child.example.com
sameer.example.com
```

Comment: My device uses POSIX, PCRE is not supported on my device and I am using a custom kernel.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, to not use `-v` in this case is just a whim, I suppose

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is you want to exclude, since you say you want to match only those in a given domain. If the words are in a file on separate lines, shouldn't a match locked to the end-of-line do?

```
grep -e '\.example\.com$' domains
```

If you want to exclude something after that, then just use `grep -v`, [it's part of POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) anyway.

Comment: he wanted to exclude `www.example.com`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, yeah, the sample output was missing that. But the question didn't say what the rule is that excludes it.