# Move files that don't match (if then)

Tags: bash

I try to filter some files I don't want to copy to another folder (`a123*.zip` in this case) and want to copy all other `*.zip` files

```
if [[ ! -f ./a123*.zip ]];  
then 
    # copy all files without a123*.zip 
fi
```

How do I trigger the copy?

Comment: After some thought I decided this is not a dupe – the linked question is *specifically* about `ls`. Since it's not appropriate to use `ls` for programmatic solutions, the answer to that question cannot be appropriate to answer this question. Thus, I think it's not a dupe.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu

Comment: @devnull Yep, that one is a much better candidate. I would change my close vote if I could.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `extglob` here:

```
shopt -s extglob
cp !(a123*.zip) /destination
```

**If you want to copy all `*.zip` files except `a123*.zip` then use:** (thanks @kojiro)

```
cp !(a123*).zip /destination
```

Comment: This will match more than just `*.zip` files, though. I think you want `!(a123*).zip`, yes?

Comment: But didn't OP write: `copy all files without a123*.zip` but yes if only `*.zip` are to be copied then `!(a123*).zip` is the right glob pattern.

Comment: Good to know it worked for you but I won't categorize it as `"dirty"` solution :)

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -and name \*.zip -not -name a123\*.zip -exec cp "{}" "$destination"
```

Comment: Please don't [parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @kojiro Thanks for the link. It makes sense. I updated my answer to use a better method to pick the files.

Comment: But `find` isn't much better, as it says in the same article. At very least, you need to use the `-print0` flag or otherwise carefully control the delimiter.

Comment: Hey, in your update 2 you need to quote those wildcards (and `$destination` too)! do you know what the shell does with wildcards???

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yes, I am aware of what shell does with wild cards. For some reason, in my testing I didn't see any difference. I agree that it's safer to escape the wild cards.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I know why it didn't make any difference in my testing. There was nothing that matched the wild card in the directory I was running `find`.

Comment: Just remove the whole suggestion to parse ls, because that's Bash pitfall #1 http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29