# Delete anything other than *.c

Tags: shell, expansion, rm

How to remove every file in the current directory except `*.c` files ?

For ex, if i do `rm *.c` it removes all the .c files, but does not remove other other files.

I just want to do the opposite.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `find`:

```
find . -not -name *.c -delete
```

The version above will delete anything which isn't in the format of `*.c` from the current directory and below.

If you want to delete all the non `*.c` files only in the current directory (and not below) you can use the switch:  `-depth 1`

```
find . -depth 1 -not -name *.c -delete
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually i wanted to use `rm` to do that. But anyways you have basically answered the question. Also from the link given by Jim in comments above i saw that we can use `shopt -s extglob` and then use the `rm !( *.c )` to do the same. Then `shopt -u extglob` when we dont want this functionality. But i guess i need to start using `find` more..

Comment: @shreyans800755  Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)