# bash to list files of a certain type but only if condition is met

Tags: bash

I am trying to list specific file extension `.vcf` using `bash`.  The issue I am having is that there might be multiple `.vcf` in the directory, but the one that is needed only does not have a `_` in them rather it is just in the format `xxx.vcf` (name.vcf).  I am not sure how to do this but the below seems close.  Thank you :).

**Directory files**

```
123.vcf
123_count.txt
123_variant_list.vcf
```

**bash**

```
select file in $(cd /home/file/overall/stats;ls *.{vcf});do break;done
        echo $file
```

**desired output**

```
123.vcf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use `find` and a simple regex:

```
find -regex '[^_]*.vcf'
```

If you do not want to use a regex, you can follow @123's suggestion and negate part of the match with regular globbing:

```
find ! -name '*_*' -name '*.vcf'
```

If you explicitly want to omit subdirectories:

```
find -maxdepth 1 ...
```

If the leading `./` that `find` prepends when you do not explicitly specify a path bothers you, you can use `basename` to remove it:

```
basename $(find ...)
```

If you plan on passing the path to some other program, the leading `./` should not be a problem.

Comment: You don't need regex. You can use  `! -name "*_*"`. Regex is less portable.

Comment: @123. That won't match the '.vcf' part.

Comment: using `regex` I get `./123.vcf` and why is there a `./` and how do I remove it?  Thank you :).

Comment: @MadPhysicist `! -name "*_*" -name "*.vcf"`

Comment: `./` is there because `find` looks in the current directory `.` if you don't tell it otherwise. You can remove it with string chopping or with `basename`.

Comment: @Chris If you have GNU find you can use printf `-printf "%f\n"`

Comment: No problem. Thanks to @123 as well for noting that you can have multiple conditions of the same type in find.

Answer (score 5):

Enable `extglob` and say:

```
$ echo !(*_*).vcf
123.vcf
```

That is: match all files not containing any `_` and ending with `.vcf`:

```
$ ls -1
123_count.txt
123.txt
123_variant_list.vcf
123.vcf
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo !(*_*).vcf
123.vcf
```

From Bash [Reference Manual → 4.3.2 The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin):

> **extglob**
>
> If set, the extended pattern matching features described above (see
>   [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)) are enabled.

More info in tzot's answer to
[How can I use inverse or negative wildcards when pattern matching in a unix/linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/217208/1983854):

> **!(pattern-list)**     Matches anything except one of the given patterns

Comment: Nice anwser! Do you know an equivalent command to `shopt -s extglob` in zsh ? I've tried `setopt extendedglob` and `set +o extendedglob` but `echo !(*_*).vcf` only prints `!(*_*).vcf`.

Comment: @cb0 [apparently](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2006/msg00727.html), `setopt extendedglob`.

Comment: @cb0 You could try `ksh_glob`, i think it's less flaky.

Comment: Thanks, my shell must be broken or sth. else. I can't get it to work :(

Comment: @cb0 oh apologies! I got your comment just when getting a downvote, so I assumed so. Removed my previous comment-sorry.

Comment: :) no problem man. Sometimes it would be nice to see who downvotes so many good answers without any comment :/

Comment: @cb0 Apparently having `SH_GLOB` set will stop parens being interpereted properly with `ksh_glob`. `The option SH_GLOB prevents bare parentheses from being used in this way`, try unsetting it and using `ksh_glob`.

Comment: Thanks nice explanation , got it finally working using `setopt KSH_GLOB`. I didn't understand how to use it when you first commented.

Answer (score 1):

You could list all files and the grep those that do not contain a "_".

```
$ file=$(ls | grep "vcf" | grep -v "_")


$ ls | grep vcf
123.vcf
123_count.txt
123_variant_list.vcf

$ echo $file
123.vcf
```

Comment: You both are right! I added `-als` by pure habit here. On my cli example i did not added it. I removed it from my post as it will not work with `-als`. I also removed first grep.