# Delete text between two strings (inclusively) several times across one line (macOS, BSD)

Tags: bash, macos, awk, sed

I have the following line:

```
name@mail.addr [The Name], name2@mail2.addr2 [The Name 2], name3@mail.addr3 [Name 3], ...
```

and so on, all on one line (`$ROW`). (It's `osascript` output based on the user's multi-choice selection from a list.)

Later on in the script I want to run a loop only over the email addresses:

```
for ADDRESS in $ROW ; do
```

which by default would use a whitespace as delimiter.

So I need to delete everything between every " [" (incl. the space before) and the following "]," … so that the result is

```
name@mail.addr name2@mail2.addr2 name3@mail.addr3 ...
```

until the end of the line (the variable).

The problem is that I'm doing this on macOS which has the BSD versions of sed, awk etc., and until now I could only find GNU solutions. I do have the coreutils installed, so I could do it with GNU, but this a script meant for macOS distribution to other Mac users, who might not have installed coreutils, so GNU sed, awk etc. are not an option.

Comment: So I assume `grep -Po '\S+@\S+' file` is not working to you...

Comment: I'm afraid no... though I've got an idea… maybe it works with `awk '{gsub}'`

Comment: if you have [extglob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu) option, you can use `"${ROW//\[*([^]])\],/}"`

Comment: @sp-asic produces irregular output in my working zsh (with zprezto); on standard macOS /bin/bash, which this script will use, it isn't working.

Maybe awk/gsub works, but if, it's not so easy due to [ and ] in $ROW. Would have to be escaped somehow, and then you'd also have to use a wildcard.

Comment: is it enabled? add `shopt -s extglob` within script to enable.. from shell you can use `shopt extglob` to check if it available.. but as you said, it may not be an option in your case

Comment: In fact, now I notice -P was not needed, so `grep -Eo '\S+@\S+' file` should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work with the bsd `grep`:

```
for address in $(echo "$ROW" | grep -Eo '[^ ]*@[^ ]*'); do
    ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this works for you:

```
sed 's/\[[^[]*\],//g' <<< $ROW
```

The command deletes everything between `[` and `],` by searching the open square bracket `\[`, followed by anything else that is not an open square bracket `[^[*]`, followed by the closing square bracket and comma `\],`.