# Bash - Separate files into different arrays based on filename

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a folder of audio files. Most are single sounds -- or soundSprites -- while some are several soundSprites concatenated into spriteLists. These spriteLists use a naming convention with a `_SL` added to the end of the file name. How can I create two arrays of soundSprites and spriteLists? I've tried using `find` to exclude the spriteLists like so:

```
soundSprites+=($(find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name "*_SL*"))
```

But this adds a `./` before every file name which I want to avoid. Instead of figuring out how to then iterate through the array and remove every `./` I can only assume there's an elegant solution to this that I'm simply unaware of.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `./` is a feature, you should be glad it's there (otherwise you end up in trouble when `find` finds files whose names start with `-` and you pass them to a command which thinks it's the name of an option which it doesn't support).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `find` here; this will fail for file names that contain characters the shell will use for word-splitting or pathname generation. Instead, use a pattern *designed* for pathname generation.

```
shopt -s extglob
soundSprites+=( !(*_SL*) )
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With the information from the best answer of this question:
[How can I use inverse or negative wildcards when pattern matching in a unix/linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/217017/2243745)
you can do:

```
    shopt  extglob
    soundSprites=(!(*_SL*))
```

Comment: chepner was a bit faster, but using += could be dangerous.
Don't forget to deactivate the extglob option if you don't need it any longer.