# Why does (*.foo|bar) cause an error, but !(*.foo|bar) does not?

Tags: bash, shell

#### Error

> line 852: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Line 852 is the last line of a function:

```
touch --reference="$KERNEL_FILE" "$moduledest"/modules.(*.bin|devname|softdep)
```

#### No error

When inserting the exclamation mark `!` before `(`:

```
touch --reference="$KERNEL_FILE" "$moduledest"/modules.!(*.bin|devname|softdep)
```

#### How to `touch` the inverse of `!(*.bin|devname|softdep)`?

```
/modules.alias.bin
/modules.builtin.bin
/modules.dep.bin
/modules.devname
/modules.softdep
/modules.symbols.bin
```

Comment: I could have sworn we had duplicates to this in the knowledgebase -- but while we have [How can I use inverse or negative wildcards when matching a pattern in UNIX/Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu/217017) and several dupes thereto, I'm not finding an exact match that comes from the perspective of asking why the syntax is valid.

Comment: On the other hand, if your real question wasn't about the error but was "what is the inverse to [a negative extglob]"?, then that's a bit easier to find duplicative questions for (one doesn't need to use a positive extglob for the purpose -- one can also enable `nullglob` and just refer to multiple distinct glob expressions).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have not much of a clue what I am doing: bash novice. Saw some existing code, needed to tweak that to the desired result. Got an error and related that error to the "exclamation mark".  I searched for the exact error and exclamation mark. With over 300 results on Stackoverflow. Gave up after scanning 200. Read a Bash manual, and documented my case at stackoverflow in the hope to find my own q&a a next time. My own stack q&a's saved me several times in the past, even years later.

Answer (score 3):

#### Extended glob

The pattern you are trying to negate match with the exclamation mark is an "extended glob". Enabled somewhere in the script with a command alike `shopt -s extglob`.

The negation form with extended globbing syntax is defined as `!(list)`:

> `!(list)` Matches anything but the given patterns.

The inverse of that negative match in this case is the syntaxis `@(list)`:

> `@(list)` Matches one of the given patterns