# Bash expression to list files beginning and ending with a pattern

Tags: bash, shell

In my shell bash, I have to select files beginning by `ab` or `xyz` and don't end by `.jpg` or `.gif`

here is what i did but it doesn't work:

`$ echo ab*[!.jpg] ab*[!.gif] xyz*[!.jpg] xyz*[!.gif]`

Comment: From where you want to short list these files? From a file? or from a Directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With bash's extended glob syntax:

```
$ touch {ab,xyz}1234.{jpg,gif,txt,doc}

$ shopt -s extglob    
$ echo @(ab|xyz)!(*@(.jpg|.gif))
ab1234.doc ab1234.txt xyz1234.doc xyz1234.txt
```

The exclamation point is for negation, and the `@` symbol is for or.

References:

- [Using OR patterns in shell wildcards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50220/using-or-patterns-in-shell-wildcards)
- [How can I use inverse or negative wildcards when pattern matching in a unix/linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu)

Comment: Thank you so much @user00001! I got it with your solution

Answer (score 3):

Using grep:

```
ls | grep -E '^ab|^xyz' | grep -E -v '\.jpg$|\.gif$'
```

`-v` is to inverse the match

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try with below command:-

```
ls {ab*,xyz*}.* | sed '/.jpg/d;/.gif/d'
```

IF you store the output into a file:-

```
ls {ab*,xyz*}.* | sed '/.jpg/d;/.gif/d' > shortedFile.txt
```

How will it work? `ls {ab*,xyz*}.*` command will list out all the files begin with `ab` and `xyz` and redirect the output to `sed` command by using `|` (pipe) and `sed` command will remove file name ended with `.jpg` and `gif`.

Hope this will help your