# How to exclude files in path directory using pathlib in python the proper way?

Tags: python, pathlib

I have a datapath to a file couple of data files, let us say data01.txt, data02.txt and so on. During processing the user will provide mask files for the data (potentially also via an external tool). Mask files will contain the string 'mask', e.g., data01-mask.txt.

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path(C:\Windowns\test\data01.txt)
dircontent = list(p.parent.glob('*'))
```

Gives me a list of all the filespath as `Path` objects including potential masks. Now I want a list that gives me the directory content but not including any file containing mask. I have [tried this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu) to use fancy regex `*![mask]*` but I do not get it to work.

Using,

```
dircontentstr = [str(elem) for elem in x]
filtereddir = [elem.find('mask') for elem in dircontentstr if elem.find('mask')==-1]
```

I can get the desired result, but it seems silly to then convert back to `Path` elements. Is there a straight forward way to exclude from the directory list?

Comment: Why not just test against the `.name` attribute of the path object?

Comment: os.listdir might help you?

Comment: @eagle33322, I want to use pathlib.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I reread my question and in trying to make a MWE, I forgot to mention, that mask is appended to any or multiple files in the folder, but I don't know which ones, so I need to use a filter on all the filenames and cannot compare one name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no need to convert anything to strings here, as `Path` objects have helpful attributes that you can use to filter on. Take a look at the [`.name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) and [`.stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) attributes; these let you filter path objects on the base filename (where `.stem` is the base name without extension):

```
dircontent = [path for path in p.parent.glob('*') if 'mask' not in path.stem]
```

Comment: Given the updated question, dircontent = [path for path in x if path.name.find('mask') == -1] works. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthiasArras: I've updated my answer to fit your question better. Don't use `.find()`, use `'mask' in ...`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Is it possible to add more conditions to the `if` ? For example I want to exclude 'MASK',  but also exclude BAK, but include TXT etc ?

Comment: @FMFF: it's just a boolean expression. `BAK` and `TXT` are extensions. presumably, so you want to use the [`.suffix` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.suffix). E.g. `if 'MASK' not in path.stem and path.suffix == '.TXT'` would include files ending in `.TXT` that have `MASK` in their file stem, etc. (note that files that end in `.TXT` can't also end in `.BAK`).

Comment: @FMFF: note that if you are looking for files with a specific, single extension, then it is easier to let the `glob()` call limit the files, e.g. `p.parent.glob('*.TXT')` would only list files ending with `.TXT`.